# Confusion on electron volt and Kelvin?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, unit-conversion, binding-energy

If an element A has a binding energy of X eV with element B, can it be said that it is equivalent to X*11600K as 1 eV approx equals 11600K.

I do not think this is correct as temp. is linked to the kinetic energy of the atoms making up the material whereas binding energy depends upon the electronic forces between the atoms in question.

Comment: Yet eV and kT are both in units of energy.

Comment: Energy is energy, whether it is kinetic or potential energy. In both cases it indicates the ability of a system to perform work. Which units one uses depends on the situation. We generally only use temperature units when the system has an actual thermodynamic temperature.

Comment: You can think of it as an (over) estimate of  the temperature which will result in the nuclei having a chance of breaking up as a result of collisions?

Answer (score 5):

1 eV is not equivalent to 11,600K, rather it is equivalent to 1.602e-19J. Both eV and J are unit of energy. K is unit of temperature.

Sometimes, you can see people using 11,600K to describe eV. This is because people are using Boltzmann constant k = 1.381e-23 J/K, which links the temperature to molecular kinetic energy. The conversion is numerical and does not necessary have physics essence in it. It is correct when you use it to interpret gas partical kinetic energy and is confusing when you use it to interpret your work.

Comment: Why is it not multiplied by 2/3 as by the equation $E = \frac32 k_B T$?

Answer (score 2):

Binding energy is usually not associated with temperature. Only a kinetic energy of **random** motion is related to temperature. You can imagine a bunch of particles at rest. Then go to some moving frame of reference. Now all particles are moving in the same direction and they have some kinetic energy. However, we will not say that the temperature of the system increased because the motion is not random. 
On the other hand, you can imagine more complicated definitions of temperature than just an energy related to the random motion. In this more complicated cases, the temperature can be for example negative. But it is not a temperature in the classical sense.

Answer (score 1):

This temperature does have a little bit of physical sense. For example, at that temperature, the compound AB has about 50% chance of falling apart within one period of bond oscillation. This is a very very crude estimate (assumes energy exchange at rates of bond vibrations), often used for estimating desorption rates.

It is common to see exp(-Eb/kT) terms in all sorts of probabilities, see [Boltzmann distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_distribution). There, binding energy/temperature is being compared to thermal energy/temperature.

Temperature is sometimes measured in electron-volts, [for example by plasma physicists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_temperature) .